"Purchase' event doesnt get triggered in GTM after redirecting from payments in WordPress
I use GTM for my website to track event , when cusomter purchases an item the Meta Pixel Helper extension can track it as "Purchase" but GTM doesnt triggers Purchase event .
I checked all triggers and tags and everything is correct .

you didn't do enough debugging. Meta pixel helper is irrelevant. Inspect the triggers that GTM uses for tracking purchases.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
